# Cant install visual studio 2013 update 5 after stopping installation

Tags: visual-studio-2013

I was trying to install an iso file I had for vs 2013 and it got stuck while installing (waited about 2 hours) so I had to cancel the installation.
Now I am trying to install it again but it keeps complaining about missing files.

I donwloaded a single install file for vs 2013, and it installed but gave the next error:

microsoft SQL server data Tools - enu (12.0.41012.0) package failed.
I went and tried to install specifically sql tools and it complained I have no visual studio installed.

I have to mention I do have visual c++ 2010 installed and seems to be fully working.

If I could I would like to remove all installations of the vs I have but it won't let me remove them either.

This is the error from the log file I get for the installation of vs 2013:

> [045C:1B74][2015-12-23T14:04:12]i000: MUX:  ExecuteError:
>   Package(SSDTJuneau_enu) failed: Error Message Id: 0 ErrorMessage: This
>   application requires Microsoft Visual Studio.  Install Microsoft
>   Visual Studio and then run the installer again.
>
> [1E54:08D0][2015-12-23T14:04:12]e000: Error 0x80070643: Failed to
>   install MSI package. [1E54:08D0][2015-12-23T14:04:12]e000: Error
>   0x80070643: Failed to execute MSI  package.
>   [045C:1B74][2015-12-23T14:04:12]e000: Error 0x80070643: Failed to
>   configure per-machine MSI package.
>
> [045C:1B74][2015-12-23T14:04:12]i000: MUX:  Installation size in bytes
>   for package: SSDTJuneau_enu MaxAppDrive: 0  MaxSysDrive: 73728 
>   AppDrive: 0  SysDrive: 73728
>
> [045C:1B74][2015-12-23T14:04:12]i000: MUX:  Return Code:0x80070643 Msi
>   Messages:0 Result Detail:0 Restart:None
>
> [045C:1B74][2015-12-23T14:04:12]i000: MUX:  Set Result: Return
>   Code=-2147023293 (0x80070643), Error Message=0, Result Detail=,
>   Vital=False, Package Action=Install, Package Id=SSDTJuneau_enu
>
> [045C:1B74][2015-12-23T14:04:12]w350: Applied non-vital package:
>   SSDTJuneau_enu, encountered error: 0x80070643. Continuing...